# Autofac - register generic type with nongeneric interface

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, ioc-container

```cs
public class CriticalAnalyzer<TContext> : ICriticalAnalyzer<object>
    where TContext : ISomeInterface
{
}
```

```cs
public class CriticalAnalyzerN2 : ICriticalAnalyzer<string>
{
}
```

So, now I`m trying to register upper types like that:

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .PublicOnly()
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICriticalAnalyzer<>))
    .OwnedByLifetimeScope()
    .SingleInstance();

// How to register same as here but remember that class could have their custom generics what we didn`t know about
```

But I`m getting an error, which is says actually not a lot of info but, as I understand the problem is in CriticalAnalyzer class (with generic)

I tried to register AsSelf()

Error:
BitMono.Protections.AntiDebugBreakpoints. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'BitMono.Protections.AntiDebugBreakpoints' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'BitMono.Core.Protecting.Analyzing.DnlibDefs.DnlibDefFeatureObfuscationAttributeHavingCriticalAnalyzer`1[BitMono.Protections.AntiDebugBreakpoints] dnlibDefFeatureObfuscationAttributeHavingCriticalAnalyzer' of constructor 'Void .ctor(BitMono.Core.Protecting.Analyzing.DnlibDefs.DnlibDefFeatureObfuscationAttributeHavingCriticalAnalyzer`1[BitMono.Protections.AntiDebugBreakpoints], BitMono.Core.Protecting.Analyzing.DnlibDefs.DnlibDefSpecificNamespaceHavingCriticalAnalyzer, BitMono.Core.Protecting.Analyzing.DnlibDefs.DnlibDefCriticalAnalyzer, Serilog.ILogger)'.
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)

Comment: Why not tell us the error though? Maybe it means something useful to us?

Comment: @DavidG error added

Answer (score 0):

So, I made smth like that:

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CriticalAnalyzer<>))
    .AsSelf()
    .OwnedByLifetimeScope()
    .SingleInstance();
```

But what if I will have more the same as this CriticalAnalyzer, how to automize registration of it?